# Condition is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am using the following codes to show post-info in genesis. but i have an issue. **I don't want to show post-info at some specific pages like blog page and homepage.**

so i have tried some ways but not working.

actually i have created page templates .. **page-blog.php** and **page-home.php**

```
remove_action( 'genesis_before_post_content', 'genesis_post_info' );
add_action( 'genesis_before_post_title', 'child_post_info' );

function child_post_info() {
    if (!is_page('blog')) {
    return;
?>

    <div class="post-info">
        <span class="date published time">
            <time class="entry-date" itemprop="startDate" datetime="<?php echo get_the_date( 'c' ); ?>" pubdate><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></time>
        </span> By 
        <span class="author vcard">
            <a class="fn n" href="<?php echo get_the_author_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>" title="View <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>'s Profile" rel="author me"><?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?></a>
        </span>
        <span class="post-comments">&middot; <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>#comments"><?php comments_number( 'Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments' ); ?></a></span>
        <?php // if the post has been modified, display the modified date
        $published = get_the_date( 'F j, Y' );
        $modified = the_modified_date( 'F j, Y', '', '', FALSE );
        $published_compare = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' );
        $modified_compare = the_modified_date( 'Y-m-d', '', '', FALSE ); 
            if ( $published_compare < $modified_compare ) {
                echo '<span class="updated"><em>&middot; (Updated: ' . $modified . ')</em></span>';
            } ?>
    </div>
<?php }
}
```

please give me some idea how can i resolve this issue.

**NOW:**

I have created a new file **meta-postinfo.php**

and save the

```
<div class="post-info">
...
</div>
```

and in functions.php file..

```
remove_action( 'genesis_before_post_content', 'genesis_post_info' );
add_action( 'genesis_before_post_title', 'child_post_info' );

function child_post_info() {
    if ( !is_home() && !is_page(array('blog', 'inspiring quotes')) ) { 
        get_template_part('meta', 'postinfo'); 
    }; 
}
```

the above code is working with blog page as well as home page, but not with '**inspiring quotes**' page although i have tried

```
    if ( !is_home() && !is_page('blog') && !is_page('inspiring quotes') ) {
```

but not working .. do u have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a given function in a template from particular pages you use the is_page() function like this (to hide a page with the about slug):

```
<?php
if ( !is_page('about') ) {
// This function will not run on the homepage
}; 
?>
```

To hide something from the home page you use is_Home

```
<?php
if ( !is_home() ) {
// This function will not run on the homepage
}; 
?>
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

EDIT: This would not be in a function called by add_action but instead could be written right into your template where ever it should display, like:

```
<?php
if ( !is_home() ) {
   <div class="post-info">
    <span class="date published time">
    // ... the rest of this display template.
   }; 
  ?>
```

If it was going to be used in multiple templates you can move it to a seperate file and use  like:

```
<?php
if ( !is_home() ) {
   get_template_part('postinfo');
   }; 
  ?>
```

Comment: not working mate .. i have an issue with blog page. i have tried is_page('blog')  .. but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear about what I was suggesting. I edited my answer

Comment: If this worked for you can you "accept" the answer?  (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)